# Using VBA and SQL, can I refer to an excel column header in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am writing a SQL query that checks excel values against a database. While running my Excel macro, I create worksheet 2 (ws2) and need to run a query which checks if each of the values in column F = table.number.

I know I can use Cells to get a single value and wrap it in a for loop but that takes up too much processing and requires too many SQL extracts. The column in `ws2` is called "**REFERENCE**" and has all the data below it. Ideally, I would like to write the SQL query like:

```
select * from table where ws2.REFERENCE = table.number
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The Worksheet ***is*** the table when you're querying Excel.

Comment: I see. I would need to access the Number column within the ws2 table though and I dont think the program knows th ename of the column. I've tried, ws2.Columns(6) as well to get the column but that didnt seem to work either.  

ws2.Number = databaseTable.number, how would I reference the ws2.Number part using an sql query?

Comment: If your worksheet has named columns, it would consider them table columns. Please show the *actual* Excel SQL call.

Comment: sql = " select * " & _
                     " from " & at & " as at," & _
                     " where at.reference = ws2.REFERENCE"

Comment: @Parfait ^ that is the verbatim query I am trying to run. I can confirm that no errors occur until it reaches "ws2.REFERENCE"

Comment: Please show the fuller VBA code block or explain how you run that `SELECT` statement in Excel.

Comment: @Parfait I moved some stuff around but this is more or less the code I am using to run the SQL. https://codeshare.io/5Xr4ml

Comment: Try appending a `$` symbol to the end of the worksheet name: `ws2$`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do the comparison in either Excel or in SQL Server, right.  I think one viable solution is to import data from SQ Server, including field names, and do compare this to what you already have in Excel.

```
Sub Conn2SQL()

    Dim cnn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim iCols As Integer

    Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
      cnn1.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=MyDBServer;uid=MyuserID;pwd=mypassword;database=MyDB"
      cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 30
      cnn1.Open

    SQry = "use MyDB select * from TableName"

    mrs.Open SQry, cnn1

    For iCols = 0 To mrs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = mrs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

    mrs.Close
    cnn1.Close

End Sub
```